# Drawing In my Charts using amcharts

Tags: javascript, amcharts

I can’t draw in my charts using drawingIconsEnabled
i need to draw in my charts an make markup 
Link my code :plnkr.co/edit/uKdqrGvMHaAx7wixax5m?p=preview

Answer (score 0):

[`drawingIcontsEnabled` is a stock chart feature](https://docs.amcharts.com/3/javascriptstockchart/StockPanel#drawingIconsEnabled), not a serial chart feature. You have to use the stock charts library instead if you need drawing functionality. Look at [this demo on AmCharts' site](https://www.amcharts.com/demos/drawing-trend-lines/) to see how it's implemented and change your code accordingly.

Note that stock charts only work with date-based data. String-based categories will not work.

The user can also enable annotations in the export menu if they want to draw on the chart as well. This works in both stock and non-stock charts.